# OOP attribute definition

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I want to define an attribute in a method:

```
class variables:
    def definition(self):
        self.word = "apple"
```

Then I want to use the defined attribute:

```
test = variables()
print test.definition.word
```

Instead of writing `'apple'` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bezejmenný.py", line 6, in <module>
    print test.definition.word
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'word'
```

Comment: That should be **two separate lines** - call the method (`test.definition()`) *then* access the attribute it creates (`print test.word`). You should really follow a structured Python OOP tutorial, this is pretty basic stuff. Also you're not compliant with [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and it's bad form to create a new attribute outside of `__init__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `definition` is a method so you need to execute it
2. Because you are assigning a variable to self, you can access it through your instance as follows

   ```
   test = variables()
   test.definition()
   print test.word
   ```

A few ideas:

- It's best practice start class names with a capital letter
- If you just want you class to have a field, you don't need your `definition` method
- Extend your class with `object` because *everything* in python is objects (python 2.x only)

  ```
  class Variables(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.word = 'I am a word'

  variables = Variables()
  print variables.word
  ```

Comment: Now `word` is a *class attribute*, which is subtly different to an *instance attribute*. It's worth noting that `object` is only needed in 2.x, and that an old-style class is still an object (it's just not an `object` - confused yet?)

Comment: I wrote the definition method becouse i used it as an exemple. Originally I   worked on method (not function, lesson learned) that loads images and saves them.

Answer (score 2):

You can access instance attribute like this:

```
test = variable()
test.definition()
print test.word
```